# Custom formula to calculate percentage in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, percentage

How can I calculate percentage of job hours in google sheet based on location marked against each employee?

| job hours | location |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | Canada |
| 32 | Singapore |
| 23 | Canada |
| % hours Canada |  |
| % hours Singapore |  |

I tried to using percentage if; but based on a given range of value how can I calculate an overall percentage of working hours  based on each location for an employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=sumif(B3:B5,"Canada",A3:A5)/sum(A3:A5)
```

Either format result as percentage (Format->Number->Percent) or multiply result by `100`.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an option combining with QUERY that will let you add as many locations as you need:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT B, SUM(A)/"&SUM(A:A)&" WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY B 
LABEL SUM(A)/"&SUM(A:A)&" 'Percentage'", 1)
```

[image]